# Calling .php within a Django/Python file

Tags: php, python, django

I am building an application in Django and want to run a .php script I already have made earlier. I need to be able to give along a string to the .php file and catch the returning output. Does anyone have an idea how to do this? Can I make some kind of http request and catch the response?

p.s. I already tried converting the php file to python script but I couldn't get it to work..

Comment: I doubt that it's impossible to convert the PHP script to Python

Comment: Didn't say it was impossible, but that I couldn't. So i figured it would be easier to just call the php file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this one, i've found it [here](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2009-October/071973.html)

```
import subprocess

#simple caller, disguard output

subprocess.call("php /path/to/my/old/script.php")

# if you want output

proc = subprocess.Popen("php /path/to/my/script.php", shell=True,
stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

script_response = proc.stdout.read()
```

Comment: Thanks, but how would I be able to insert a input with this method? I have to input a string, catch that in the php file and then catch the output again in the python script. Any idea?

Comment: @Javaaaa `proc = subprocess.Popen("php /path/to/my/script.php?myinput=whateverhere", shell=True,
stdout=subprocess.PIPE)` what you tried that?

Comment: I am using Popen in django but getting an error as follows "Errno 2] No such file or directory" Exception Location:  /usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py in _execute_child, line 1259

Answer (score 0):

If it's a php file served by web server (I assume that from your HTPP request question) do something like this:

```
In [1]: import urllib2
In [2]: resp = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.starenka.net/ip')
In [3]: resp.read()
Out[3]: 'ip: 62.245.xx.xx\nlocal ip: 62.245.xx.xx\nhostname:  ip-62-245-xx-xx.net.upcbroadband.cz\n'
In [4]: resp.info()
Out[4]: <httplib.HTTPMessage instance at 0x9f8720c>
```

Comment: Thanks, but how would I be able to insert a input with this method? I have to input a string, catch that in the php file and then catch the output again in the python script. Any idea? – Javaaaa 0 secs ago edit